# Alloy - Generate .xml instance from .als

Tags: java, analyzer, alloy

I need to generate random .xml instances from an .als in my program. I managed to do that by running alloy in background (invisible JFrame) and calling the doOpen, doExecuteLatest and doShowLatest functions. But having to wait alloy to start every time I run my code is a pain. I think it would be more efficient if I simply used the alloy code section that does this procedure (I imagine that would be kodkod).
Does anyone know how to do that? I found alloy's code to be pretty confusing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Alloy API.
Generating an instance and writing it as an XML file can be easily done following those steps:

1. Read the alloy model from its source file.

   > model = CompUtil.parseEverything_fromFile(null, null,
   >   "yourmodel.als");
2. Get the command to execute. for example :

   > Command cmd=model.getAllCommands().get(0);
3. Execute the model using the command obtained in step 2

   > A4Solution solution=  TranslateAlloyToKodkod.execute_command(null,
   >   model.getAllReachableSigs(), cmd, new A4Options());
4. Write the solution generated in step 3

> solution.writeXML("path/to/your.xml");

Examples can be found in the edu.mit.csail.sdg.alloy4whole package of the Alloy jar file

Comment: You have no idea of how helpful this was! Thank you so much!

Comment: How to iterate over the solutions? (asked in <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227303/how-to-iterate-over-solutions-using-the-alloy-api>). Thanks.